# My 19 year old dying cat bit my chest and punctured the skin last night

Tags: cats

My 19 year old cat must have had a seizure the night before last and was twitching and pawing with a blurry gaze on her face.  I know it's an end of life late stage kidney failure as the vet had just tested her a couple of months ago and said she was stage 3 with high blood pressure.  I held her most of the day.
She was soaking wet when I picked her up and I held her on a towel for hours as she kept pawing with her front paws and hind legs outstretched and stiff.  Out of nowhere when I tried to reposition her she turned her head and bit me on my chest.  It was unintentional as she really is incoherent.  It did puncture the skin.  I washed it with peroxide and alcohol and then warm salt water and neosporin.  I have too many pre existing conditions to list.  A friend had gotten bitten on her hand recently and ended up in the ER.  She had three days of the special amoxcillion for cat bites left.  I started taking it last night and 12 hours later my second pill.  It is not as red and not swollen.  I did call the doctor's office but they never called back.  Should I wait and see and watch it or call the doctor on call for the weekend to get the rest of the prescription since cat bites can be lethal.  Thanks for your advice.  Maxine

Comment: this is not about your cat it is about your health this makes it off topic here,you need to ask your doctor about this.

Comment: if you have started taking antibiotics you need to continue taking antibiotics for the duration your doctor has prescribed even if you start to feel better.

Comment: i only have 3 days worth of the antibiotics given to me by a friend who had them leftover from her cat bite that ended her up in the ER.  Of course it's saturday and no doc office is opened here.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's address the elephant in the room. *If you don't take the full course of antibiotics prescribed, you encourage the development of antibiotic-resistant strains of bacteria*. Antibiotics are an all-or-nothing medicine. That's a big part of the reason why they're prescription-only in the first place. Your friend should **NOT** have had any "left over" antibiotics, and you should **NOT** have taken a partial course of them.

Now, on to the actual question itself. Cat bites can be nasty, they have a lot of bacteria and other potential contaminates in their mouths. But, based on what you described, I don't think its infected. You did the right thing by washing the wound immediately with disinfectants. I would just monitor it. If it starts showing signs of infection (swelling, redness, soreness, discharge, etc.) you would probably want to consider going to an emergency clinic or the ER.

Comment: thank goodness the doctor phoned in the full prescription.  It is the same exact ones I started so will continue the regimen until all pills are gone.  Today you an barely see the cat bite at all.  Thank you!

Comment: "Your friend should NOT have had any "left over" antibiotics" I've had occasions where I was prescribed antibiotics for X days, and there were pills left over in the bottle the pharmacist gave me afterwards because they gave me more than X days of pills.

Comment: @nick012000 Are you sure you're counting your pills correctly, and not accidentally skipping doses? Because I've never received extra of any medicine from any pharmacy I've ever been to. If you *are* right and they're giving you extra, I'd consider switching pharmacies, because if they're being that careless with basic counting, what else are they being careless about? At any rate, you should flush those leftover antibiotics down the toilet as soon as reasonably practical, because they are of no use to anybody.